# print last field from line + alternative for awk

Tags: bash, text-processing, solaris, cut, tr

Due to technical reason on my Solaris machine,  I can't use `awk` in order to print the last field in line.

What are the other alternatives to `awk` that print the last field from line (using `cut` or `tr` ...etc)?

Example 1:

```
/usr/bin/hostname
machine1b
/usr/bin/hostname  | /usr/bin/sed 's/\(.\{1\}\)/\1 /g' |  /usr/bin/awk  '{print $NF}'
b
```

Example2

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | /usr/bin/awk  '{print $NF}'

5
```

Comment: What is your goal? Given that `sed` code seem you need the last _character_, not the last _field_. To get the hostname's last character in `bash`, `${HOSTNAME: -1}` may be enough. (Not sure if Solaris sets such variable.)

Comment: the sed code only seperate between characters , so I will can to print the last word/character , I still need alternative for awk , because I have other examples in my code ,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Perl

```
echo foo bar baz | perl -pe 's/.*[ \t]//'
```

If you have to strip trailing spaces first, do it like this:

```
echo "foo bar baz " | perl -lpe 's/\s*$//;s/.*\s//'
```

The following was contributed by [mr.spuratic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/31352/mr-spuratic) in a comment:

```
echo "foo bar baz " | perl -lane 'print $F[-1]'
```

## Bash

```
echo foo bar baz | while read i; do echo ${i##* }; done
```

or is `bash` is not your default shell:

```
echo foo bar baz | bash -c 'while read i; do echo ${i##* }; done'
```

If you have to strip a single trailing space first, do

```
echo "foo bar baz " | while read i; do i="${i% }"; echo ${i##* }; done
```

## tr and tail

```
echo foo bar baz | tr ' ' '\n' | tail -n1
```

although this will only work for a single line of input, in contrast to the solutions above. Suppressing trailing spaces in this approach:

```
echo "foo bar baz " | tr ' ' '\n' | grep . | tail -n1
```

Comment: To add to your comprehensive list: `perl -an` allows the use of the `F` array like awk's `$1`, `$2` etc, though it is zero-indexed and there is no special `NF` so you use `$F[-1]` (or the slightly unpretty `$F[$#F]`).

Answer (score 2):

Using Cut:

Last field:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | rev | cut -f1 -d ' '
```

Last character:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | rev | cut -c1
```

Comment: Yeah, but isn't "field" the entire word or number? Try your command with `51` instead of `5`. Check out my [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70892/13136).

Comment: Just pipe to `rev` again at the end to reverse back.

Answer (score 2):

`echo hello my friend | tac -s' ' | tr '\n' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f 1`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

`sed -E -e 's/.* ([^ ]+)$/\1/'`

```
% echo 1 2 3 4 5 | sed -E -e 's/.* ([^ ]+)$/\1/'
5
```

Comment: not work on my solaris machine - echo 1 2 3 4 5 | sed -E -e 's/.* ([^ ]+)$/\1/'
sed: illegal option -- E

Comment: try something like this: `sed -e 's/.* \([^ ]\{1,\}\)/\1/'`
Sorry, I don't have any Solaris machine to actually test it.